# Arduino is not able to run any sketches

Tags: arduino

recently I started using my arduino again, but it can no longer run sketches or anything. All I get  is this error:

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException  at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:152)
    at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:77)
    at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:732)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:703)
    at processing.app.Editor$UploadHandler.run(Editor.java:2047)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Error touching serial port 'COM4'.
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:107)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:136)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM4; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
    at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:164)
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:101)
    ... 6 more
```

I tried restarting pc,  using different port, stopping other devices in device manager from using the port,  reinstalling the IDE, and more.
nothing works.
It cant even run blink without throwing this error.
I am using windows 10 pc, Arduino MKR WIFI 1010 , with a usb 3.0 cable, the Arduino *used* to work too.
none of the other answers on the internet has worked for me.

could this be a problem?   ->  [image]

EDIT: I figured out what was wrong. the cable I was connecting to my arduino and computer was ONLY a charging cable, it had no ability to send serial data across to the arduino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was using the wrong type of cable for connecting my arduino to computer

Answer (score 0):

this can happen if you have other stuff connected to your arduino that sends or receives data, like a bluetooth module.
Try disconnecting everything from the board and resetting the board, then connect the usb to your arduino

Comment: I have nothing directly connected to my Arduino.